# Add Ethernet to HP Color LaserJet CP1215?

Tags: hp, ethernet, printer

On the back of my HP Color LaserJet CP1215 there is a USB port and a spot where an Ethernet port might possibly be located.  It is covered by a black plastic insert, and the metal on the back has the ethernet diagram indicating that would be an ethernet port.

Is it possible to purchase a card or module of some sort and install it inside the printer to add ethernet capability (instead of using a usb to ethernet print server) ?

If so, can you point me at what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a network card to this type of printer. The dummy-port is there because they use similar cases on all of their models. You can add an USB printer server.

Answer (score 0):

No, the CP1215 does not support Ethernet. You could add a Network->USB Print Server, but it would not integrate with the printer.

The CP1215 shares much of it's design with the CP1515 and CP1518, which do have Ethernet connectivity, hence the plug hole in the case.